# Histogram in bookdown document appears two times

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, bookdown

When I do `bookdown::render_book(...)` on my document which contains the following code segment

````
#```{r eval=TRUE, include=TRUE, echo=FALSE}  # only that you can see my chunk options (it's of course not commented out)

# My data for a histogram
Distance = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 5, sd = 0.5)

# Creating the histogram
hist(Distance,
    freq=FALSE,
    xlim = c(0, 9),
    ylim = c(0, max(hist(Distance)$density + 0.2)),
    xlab = "Distance [mm]",
    ylab = "Density",
    main = "Histogram")
abline(v=5.5,lwd=2,lty=2,col="red")

#```
````

I get this Output

[image]

and like the code suggest the first histogram shouldn't appear - the one with the *Frequency* on the y-axis.

**Question**: What should I do to avoid the appearance of the first histogram?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the line `ylim = c(0, max(hist(Distance)$density + 0.2)),` where you call the histogram of Distance. This plots the histogram of Distance before returning the values you need as arguments for your real plot.

If you want to use a property of a histogram as an argument, you should store the histogram in a variable before drawing your real histogram and then just refer to it.

So, before doing anything else, use `h = hist(Distance)`

Then, you may change the ylim specification to: `ylim = c(0, max(h$density + 0.2)),`

There should only be one histogram, then.

Comment: Like the commenter above guessed. To get no plot you must add your `h = hist(Distance)` in a new code chunk with the options `{r eval=TRUE, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}` - set include to FALSE.